# Google MapView control does not "swallow" gestures, causing containing scrollview to consume them

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a Google MapView control on a view that is embedded in a UISCrollView control (Google Maps iOS SDK using Xamarin.iOS mono binding).

The problem is that the control doesn't "swallow" swipe gestures. So when the user swipes on the map, the swipe is also handled by the containing scrollview. This is a real "show stopper" and makes the MapView control unusable for me.

I tried deriving a class from MapView and overriding the methods GestureRecognizerShouldBegin and TouchesBegan but they never get called.

It seems to be a problem that is related with the GMSMapView control itself, not with the Xamarin binding:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5311

How can I prevent the UISCrollView from receiving/handling gestures that are made on the MapView control?

Answer (score 1):

With the current (1.3.0) version of the Google Maps SDK, you can access the following settings:

```
self.mapView.settings.scrollGestures = NO;
self.mapView.settings.zoomGestures = NO;
self.mapView.settings.tiltGestures = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

you might find how to avoid event propagation [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3574/avoid-event-propagation-to-scrollview/p1)

Hope this helps

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can get around it by writing a UIGestureRecognizer subclass that eats the touches for any continuous gesture and then adding that recognizer to the GMSMapView via its gestureRecognizers property.

Google does not use gesture recognizers in their SDK so right now this doesn't interfere with the map, although future updates might change that. I don't know how to define custom recognizers in MonoTouch, but it seems to be possible (http://docs.xamarin.com/samples/Touch).

This gesture recognizer will need to implement something like these touch handling methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled;
}
```

This will cause the map to eat any touches on it, like MKMapKit, stopping any scroll views further up the hierarchy seeing them. I'm afraid I don't know the C#/Xamarin.iOS equivalent code, hope this is useful.

Comment: Looks like google have fixed the issue with the map failing to consume touches in [version 1.3.0](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases#version_130_-_may_2013)

Comment: Maybe not. They attached a UIPanGestureRecognizer to the map by default, but this can fail if the user has multiple fingers down and starts rotating/tilting a lot. It's a lot better than it was in 1.2.0 though.

Answer (score 0):

For the reference of future readers of the post, following two improvements were made in further releases of google maps sdk for ios under resolved issues part:

1, Version 1.3.0 - May 2013 : Touches are consumed by GMSMapView, allowing use within objects such as a scroll view

2, Version 1.3.1 - June 2013: Touches are consumed more agressively by GMSMapView